# Create binary categorical variables in pandas - combine 4 categories into 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have the following pandas dataframe, where the column 'Status' consists of 4 categorical values - 'Open', 'Closed', 'Solved' and 'Pending'.

```
0   250635                      Comcast Cable Internet Speeds  22-04-15   
1   223441       Payment disappear - service got disconnected  04-08-15   
2   242732                                  Speed and Service  18-04-15   
3   277946  Comcast Imposed a New Usage Cap of 300GB that ...  05-07-15   
4   307175         Comcast not working and no service to boot  26-05-15   

  Date_month_year         Time        Received Via      City     State  \
0       22-Apr-15   3:53:50 PM  Customer Care Call  Abingdon  Maryland   
1       04-Aug-15  10:22:56 AM            Internet   Acworth   Georgia   
2       18-Apr-15   9:55:47 AM            Internet   Acworth   Georgia   
3       05-Jul-15  11:59:35 AM            Internet   Acworth   Georgia   
4       26-May-15   1:25:26 PM            Internet   Acworth   Georgia   

   Zip code  Status Filing on Behalf of Someone  
0     21009  Closed                          No  
1     30102  Closed                          No  
2     30101  Closed                         Yes  
3     30101    Open                         Yes  
4     30101  Solved                          No
```

I would like to combine the 'Open' and 'Pending' categories as 'Open' column and 'Closed' and 'Solved' as 'Closed' column with 0 and 1 binaries. If I use `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Status'])` I get the following output with 4 new columns for the 4 values but I only want 2, as mentioned earlier. I couldn't find any previous thread here on this so please suggest any possible method. Thank you.

```
0          22-Apr-15   3:53:50 PM  Customer Care Call    Abingdon  Maryland   
1          04-Aug-15  10:22:56 AM            Internet     Acworth   Georgia   
2          18-Apr-15   9:55:47 AM            Internet     Acworth   Georgia   
3          05-Jul-15  11:59:35 AM            Internet     Acworth   Georgia   
4          26-May-15   1:25:26 PM            Internet     Acworth   Georgia   
             ...          ...                 ...         ...       ...   
2219       04-Feb-15   9:13:18 AM  Customer Care Call  Youngstown   Florida   
2220       06-Feb-15   1:24:39 PM  Customer Care Call   Ypsilanti  Michigan   
2221       06-Sep-15   5:28:41 PM            Internet   Ypsilanti  Michigan   
2222       23-Jun-15  11:13:30 PM  Customer Care Call   Ypsilanti  Michigan   
2223       24-Jun-15  10:28:33 PM  Customer Care Call   Ypsilanti  Michigan   

      Zip code Filing on Behalf of Someone  Status_Closed  Status_Open  \
0        21009                          No              1            0   
1        30102                          No              1            0   
2        30101                         Yes              1            0   
3        30101                         Yes              0            1   
4        30101                          No              0            0   
       ...                         ...            ...          ...   
2219     32466                          No              1            0   
2220     48197                          No              0            0   
2221     48197                          No              0            0   
2222     48197                          No              0            0   
2223     48198                         Yes              0            1   

      Status_Pending  Status_Solved  
0                  0              0  
1                  0              0  
2                  0              0  
3                  0              0  
4                  0              1  
             ...            ...  
2219               0              0  
2220               0              1  
2221               0              1  
2222               0              1  
2223               0              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with

```
df['Status_open'] = 0
df['Status_closed'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Open') | (df['Status'] == 'Pending'), 'Status_open'] = 1
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Closed') | (df['Status'] == 'Solved'), 'Status_closed'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the underlying principle:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if 'Open' in row['Status']:
            df.at[i,'Open'] =  True # or any other value 
        if 'Pending' in row['Status']:
            df.at[i,'Open'] =  True # or any other value
        if  'Closed' in row['Status']:
            df.at[i,'Closed'] =  True # or any other value
        if  'Solved' in row['Status']:
            df.at[i,'Closed'] =  True # or any other value
```

You iterate through the column check for any value and if the value is found you set a boolean value in the new column "Open". Naturally, you'll need to create the column "Open" before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

(Not tested with a pc)

I think it can be done in this manner:

```
open_ls = ['Open', 'Pending']
df['New_Status'] = df['Status'].apply(lambda x: 'Open' if x in open_ls else 'Closed')
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['New_Status'])
```